# Spring Security Role Based Authorization with Independent Authentication System

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to use Spring Security's `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")` annotations to secure my API, however, I must use my company's centralized authentication system, instead of having the user log in through Spring-Security.

To be very clear on what that means:

- My app may not ask the user for a password
- The user will already be authenticated before getting anywhere near my app. If they aren't, I am just redirecting back to the central authentication server.

What I do have access to is a mapping of users to roles, so I've implemented a custom `UserDetailsService` based on [this tutorial](https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-db-example).

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Users> optionalUsers = usersRepository.findByUserId(username);

        optionalUsers
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));
        return optionalUsers
                .map(CustomUserDetails::new).get();
    }
}
```

And inject it into Spring Security in a configuration file:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsersRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

        http.addFilterAt(
            new TrivialFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**/secured/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and().formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }

}
```

This works very well. It is successfully evaluating the user roles and allowing/denying access based on the `@PreAuthorize` annotation. I've even added a filter to the Servlet filter chain which I can eventually use to verify authentication myself. (Right now it just logs and calls `chain.doFilter(req, res)`.)

So how do I stop Spring-Security from asking for a password, while keeping this other good stuff intact?

It seems, if I remove any part of the `HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()` method chain, that, while it might disable the login screen, it will, for any method with the `@PreAuthorize` annotation, just assume an unauthorized user. The request doesn't access the `CustomUserDetailsService` class. (Though it does still pass through the `TrivialFilter` class.) It just responds with a 403 code.

I can have my filter extract the username from the request and and validate it. I just need to know how to completely replace the basic username/password system, with my filter.

Comment: When you say "authenticated", what does that mean exactly? Spring Security doesn't know about your user, so it's not authenticated *to it*. Perhaps you are looking for either SAML or OAuth with tokens granted by a centralized company server.

Comment: When I say that the user is "authenticated," I mean that my filter will be able to tell, based on an item in the request, whether the user has gone to the central authentication system and had their credentials validated. I can't talk about it more specifically, for security reasons. I want Spring Security to perform only authorization, and not authentication.

Comment: You *have* to authenticate to Spring Security. That authentication can take the form of an assertion from your SSO system, but it has to be passed over somehow. It looks like SAML is probably the best approach.